# How can I open same activity page when I click on home button and activity goes to background of emulator?

Tags: android, android-activity

When I click on the home button of the emulator my activity (Submit.java) goes to background.
But when I open again my App its start from splash screen instead from the Submit.java class.

splash screen

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();
            }
        }, 3000);

    }
```

Comment: Please paste your code.

Comment: @chntgomez it is part of activity life cycle. but i m so   confuse where i will use OnResume(),method in my activity.

Comment: The onResume() method will be called only by the application lifecycle. Any code that you put in there will execute. DO NOT MANUALLY CALL IT. Could you paste your Splash method?

Comment: Check my splash screen